# iPhone how do I programmatically substitute a degree symbol for the letter o in a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ascii, symbols

I know how to replace text in a string. But that's using keyboard (ASCII) characters. In Objective C, how do I indicate a degree symbol? Also, how do I get the ASCII code for a character?

Comment: I use http://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/ when plumbing the depths of characters.  You can search by name, see the UTF8 encoding for a character, the \uXXXX number, HTML &#176; / &deg;, etc. Also displays the glyph, if available, in the fonts you have installed. Various tabs give all kinds of Unicode info on the character, including "similar" characters (\u00b0 turns up four: \u02da, \u030a, \u2070, \u2218).  **Highly** recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find characters not on your keyboard, select "Special Characters…" on the Edit menu.

To find ASCII values, look on http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: ♭♭♭♭ here is the symbol for a flatted note in music. Would I need to use a specific font in order to get that symbol? And how would I know what escape sequence to use?

Comment: @Scott use the Special Characters palette to find the letter.  The tooltip (hover your mouse over the char) has the "Unicode:" info, which is your escape sequence (prefixed by `\u`.

Answer (score 10):

The degree symbol is <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> => `°`.  I believe you can also do: `@"\u00B0"`.

To get the ASCII code for a character, just get the character into a `char` and cast the `char` to an `int`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a superfast response. This also yields a degree symbol: @"\xC2\xB0" .

Comment: That should be shift-option-8. The symbol you gave is a somewhat similar but unrelated small superscript circle that isn't used in English.

Comment: @Chuck huh, I never knew about shift-opt-8.  I believe that opt-0 is technically the male ordinal, but it looked close enough for me.  :)  Editing answer.

Comment: Actually, how the "male ordinal" symbol looks depends on the font. On some systems, it looks a lot like a degree symbol. On others (such as the one I'm on now), it has a line underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Option shift 8 also gives a similar character. It's the one I always use and I'm not sure of the difference between the two, except the SO font option 0 has a line under it.

Option+Shift+8 = `°`
Option+0 = `º`